Git filter only right root
Given repository with two roots how can I filter commits descended from only one of them?
A--C--D (HEAD)
  /
 B

I tried git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' -- B..D but it's rewriting entire history of A.
Essentially need to rewrite commits returned by git log --ancestry-path=B D
I want to preserve C merge so the result should be:
A--C'--D'
  /
B'

UPDATE 1
Changed log command from git log --ancestry-path B..D which does not include root commit B
UPDATE 2
C^..D works as per accepted answer by eliminating leftmost parent of C but turns out ancestry-path works too. As do most flags accepted by git log (that go to git rev-list).
So the most direct way to rewrite commits from B to D is by
git filter-branch \
  --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' \
  -- --ancestry-path=B D

PS. My ancestry-path example had B and D reversed before this update.

Is B-C realy just 2 commits ?

no, it's a minimized example

I think I deciphered your question: commits B..C are not signed, you want to sign them with your key, then you need to also sign the merge commit and the following ones ?

To have a range that includes everything except "the left of C", one way to write it is: C^..D. You may try to feed that range to your git filter-branch ... command.

By the way: git filter-repo is the official replacement for git filter-branch. I suggest searching (google or SO or chatgpt) for "how can I sign commits using git filter-repo ?".

I found git-filter-repo much harder to work with. It insists on using fresh git clone and filters have to be written as python scripts which is not great for one-off things

And also I couldn't find examples how to follow only one root with git-filter-repo. In fact now I know that ancestry-path is the exact git option I want, I went and searched their repo for that word and found nothing useful. Google also yields nothing and ChatGPT says it's not directly supported. So filter-branch it is.

One way to specify "all the ancestors of D, without the left ancestors of C" is:
# all the parents of D,
# except the ones reachable from the first parent of C
C^..D

For illustration: if you wanted to exclude the right ancestors of C, this would be:
C^2..D


This does the trick, thanks! Although it does so indirectly by elimination of unwanted paths rather than inclusion of desired roots. I found out I can just pass --ancestry-path=B D to filter-branch too to express my requirement more directly.
